# AngularJS: How to see post result from API

Tags: angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

I am new to AngularJS and have a basic application set up with a front end that uses a web api to interact with a database.

I am trying to create a log in screen so I have this as my controller,

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, loginService) {

    $scope.authenticateLogin = function () {

        // get record
        var user = {
            Username: $scope.username,
            Password: $scope.password
        };


        var promisePost = loginService.post(user);
        promisePost.then(function (result) {
            var res = result.data;
            //TODO: set permissions
        },
            function (errorResult) {
                console.log("Unable to log in. :" + errorResult);
            });
    }
});
```

Which links to my service,

```
app.service('loginService', function ($http) {

    this.post = function (user) {
        return $http.post(toApiUrl('login'), user);
    }

    function toApiUrl(actionUrl) {
        return appBaseApiUrl + actionUrl;
    }
});
```

This then links to my API,

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/login
    public void Post(UserLogin user)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
//checks if valid
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that result is always empty regardless of what authorization happened in the API, and since I am doing a post I can't send data back.

Is there a way in Angular to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: When I used Firefox I can see console.log results.

Comment: What type of response are you giving back to the client-side? You could check the `response.status` returned from your post.

Comment: Also, I think it's important to say that you *can* send data back from a post.

Comment: At the moment there isn't really a response, but i would want to use any potential response to then go and define the users role and what they can see on the site. The result that comes back from the promisePost is just empty since my API method is not returning anything. How would you go about sending data back witha  post in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing something like the following on your Controller, and then taking a look at the response in Angular.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Authorize(User user)
    {
        var superAwesomeUserChecker = new SuperAwesomeUserChecker();
        var result = superAwesomeUserChecker.Check(user);
        if (result.IsAuthorized)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized(result);
        }
    }
```

You actually don't have to return content, you could just return `Ok()` or `Unauthorized()`. It depends on how your overall authentication process works.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to use this method but am encountering a problem. When I return from the method is it not returning back to the line var res = result.data in my javascript. If i leave this function  blank then it does, so something is going wrong.